# Use HasKey to find entity without explicitly specifying all keys in a query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

With EF you can specify a composite key with `HasKey` so I suppose there is a way to use an entity as a parameter to some API to find it in a database but I cannot figure out how.

The `Find` API that I was hoping to use, requires an array of key values but what I'm looking for is something like this:

```cs
var setting = new Setting { Name = "WindowSize" };
setting = context.Find(setting);
```

Since I can specify all the keys via `modelBuilder.Entity<Setting>.HasKey(s => new { s.Name })` there must be a way to reuse it. Do you know an API or a *trick* to make it work this way?

The `Setting` model is exchangable and might have other key columns. I'd like to be able to automatically find it without having to specify the criteria twice.

This means there can be:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Setting>.HasKey(s => new { s.Name, s.Version })
```

I'd like this definition be reused for querying without me having to say `Find("name", "version")` etc. but `context.SomeAPI(settingWithTwoKeys)`.

Comment: Don't know whether such functionality is given out-of-the-box or not. But, if not you can do it yourself. In EF you already can retrieve key properties and by using `Expression`s you can generate that query dynamically.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev yeah, this would be the last resort solution ;-) What else would be `HasKey` good for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built in to EF Core that does this, but it's not hard to write an extension method for `.Find` that would do it for you.  Here's a sample method (untested) that does this.

(NB: When you call this method, you can rely on generic argument inference and only pass in the entity itself - like `context.Find(settingWithTwoKeys)`).

```cs
public static TEntity Find<TEntity>(this DbContext context, TEntity keyObject) 
{
    var entityType = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity));
    var pk = entityType.FindPrimaryKey();

    var keyArgs = new List<object>();
    foreach(var pkProperty in pk.Properties)
    {
        var propValueInKeyObject = pkProperty.PropertyInfo.GetValue(keyObject);
        keyArgs.Add(propValueInKeyObject);
    }

    return context.Find<TEntity>(keyArgs);
}
```

Your second question - what's `HasKey` for.  You use it any time your DB implementation *does not* match EF Convention.  Your `Setting` entity is a good example.  There's no convention in EF that would allow it to automatically identify that `Name` and `Version` are the PKs.  You need to use `HasKey` in the model builder to tell it.

Comment: Oh! Nice one. When you know about the existence of `FindPrimaryKey` this is easy, indeed ;-]